# Cannot add Google Account to Dolphin Kubuntu 23.04

Tags: kubuntu, online-accounts, kde-connect

I cannot add any google account .

I tried online accounts in settings but web auth hangs.

I added kio, both via Discover and Terminal and Google Accounts now shows in Dolphin.However, when I try to add a G a/c, the same happens and I get this message:

*There was an error while trying to process the request: Access grant not present*

Any ideas?